# Resize an image- error A generic error occurred in GDI+

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, image

I'm trying to resize an image but when I'm getting to this line of code: 
resized.Save(physicalPath, Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)

it's throwing an error: A generic error occurred in GDI+.
Does someone ran into that error before???

Here is my fully code:

```
Dim original As Image = Image.FromFile(physicalPath)
        Dim resized As Image = ResizeImage(original, New Size(100, 100))
        Dim memStream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
        resized.Save(physicalPath, Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
```

Function for resize:

```
 'The method takes two mandatory parameters: the image to be resized and the new size it is to be resized to. 
    'An optional third parameter specifies whether to preserve the image's original aspect ratio
    Public Shared Function ResizeImage(ByVal image As Image, _
ByVal size As Size, Optional ByVal preserveAspectRatio As Boolean = True) As Image

        'If we are not going to preserve the aspect ratio of the original image, then we simply set the height and width of the new image accordingly. 
        'However, if we do wish to preserve the aspect ratio, then the situation is a little more complex: Firstly, 
        'we need to calculate the percentage difference,in each axis (height and width), between the original image and the desired size. 
        'Then we use whichever difference is the smaller to calculate the new height and width of the new image:
        Dim newWidth As Integer
        Dim newHeight As Integer
        If preserveAspectRatio Then
            Dim originalWidth As Integer = image.Width
            Dim originalHeight As Integer = image.Height
            Dim percentWidth As Single = CSng(Size.Width) / CSng(originalWidth)
            Dim percentHeight As Single = CSng(Size.Height) / CSng(originalHeight)
            Dim percent As Single = If(percentHeight < percentWidth, percentHeight, percentWidth)
            newWidth = CInt(originalWidth * percent)
            newHeight = CInt(originalHeight * percent)
        Else
            newWidth = Size.Width
            newHeight = Size.Height
        End If

        'Next, we create a blank bitmap using our new dimensions
        Dim newImage As Image = New Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight)
        'Finally, we use the graphics handle of the new bitmap to draw the original image onto our new bitmap and return it:

        Using graphicsHandle As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newImage)
            graphicsHandle.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
            graphicsHandle.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight)
        End Using
        Return newImage
    End Function
```

Comment: Have you looked at the large list of "Related" questions, that all mention  this error in their title? Also: where is the stack trace?

Comment: Yes I'm still looking to find an answer but I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yws82c40(v=vs.110).aspx) overload of the `DrawImage` method. Use a Rectangle to define the area.

```
graphicsHandle.DrawImage(image, New Rectangle(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight))
```